# What is the .net5 replacement for 'await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ReCAPTCHAVerificationResponse>()'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, recaptcha, blazor-server-side

https://github.com/sample-by-jsakamoto/Blazor-UseGoogleReCAPTCHA
is a sample implementation of reCaptcha V2 for Blazor. It contains a class named SampleApi which in turn contains the following line that fails to compile:
`var verificationResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ReCAPTCHAVerificationResponse>();`

Somewhere I found the suggestion to use:
`var verificationResponse = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ReCAPTCHAVerificationResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());`
but it did not work. It compiled but did not provide a usable verificationResponse.

I got it to work by installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client, but it is deprecated. Seems like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Newtonsoft.Json, you're looking for something like

```
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReCAPTCHAVerificationResponse>(content);
```

If you're using System.Text.Json (Microsoft's flavor and recommended by them over Newtonsoft.Json for the most part)

```
var response = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ReCAPTCHAVerificationResponse>();
```

However, this is not unique to Blazor nor .NET 5.

Comment: Your solution is exactly as it is in the reCaptcha sample, which I went back and revisited. Turns out they too have Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client installed. Just my bad for missing it.